# How to print out the results:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print this code but I keep getting errors when I use the print command in Python 2.7 

So I pretty much understand how the interpreter reads and executes this program. What would be the ideal location to put *"print s"* to see the results on the screen? Thank you very much.

```
n = raw_input('input an integer value to compute its factorial:\n')
n = int(n)

def f(n):
    if n==0:                    
        return 1                
    else:
        m = f(n-1)
        s = n * m
        return s
```

Comment: What errors? You're not even showing code that tries to print here...

Comment: That is correct. I was trying to (print s) instead of printing f(..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, you probably want something closer to this:

```
def f(n):
    if n==0:                    
        return 1                
    else:
        m = f(n-1)
        s = n * m
        return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = raw_input('input an integer value to compute its factorial:\n')
    n = int(n)
    result = f(n)
    print result
    # or alternatively for the last two lines, if you don't want to save the result
    print f(n)
```

This is so that when you just execute this script from IDLE (or directly from the command line) it runs the `if __name__` block, but otherwise it just defines the function.

Comment: Thanks man. I just figured it out. I needed to print the function itself.

Comment: @Quester if my answer helped you out I would highly appreciate it if you clicked the check mark under the answer score on the left.

Answer (score 3):

I'd move the definition of `f` to the top, above your call to `raw_input`. Then at the very end, you can call `f` with `n` and print the result:

```
print f(n)
```

If you wanted to, you could store the result in a variable, although there's no advantage here:

```
result = f(n)
print result
```

Comment: Could someone explain why they downvoted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the return value of the function and not just `s`, then you can store the return value and print that:

```
n = raw_input('input an integer value to compute its factorial:\n')
n = int(n)

def f(n):
    if n==0:                    
        return 1                
    else:
        m = f(n-1)
        s = n * m
        return s

result = f(n)
print result
```